# Android Annotations in Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

I'm new to Android Studio and gradle, so I'm not sure on how to configure correctly my project to use android annotatios.

I have followed [this](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/) tutorial, and ended up with this build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 20
   buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.test"
      minSdkVersion 11
      targetSdkVersion 20
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
         runProguard false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

configurations {
   apt
}

apt {
   arguments {
      androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
      resourcePackageName "com.example.test"
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"
   compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

Also changed the .idea/compiler.xml to enable annotation processing

```
<profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="true">
```

Gradle syncs successfully, however no file is generated. I'm able to build the app, but when I try to add the underscore to my AndroidManifest.xml file, it gives me this error:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity_'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you "Make" the project?

Comment: When running make Android Studio should call all annotation processors. Did you check the build log to see actually what was triggered?

Comment: Running make project,and checking the console, I could not find anything saying that is calling the processors.
So it's not calling? Or am I looking on the wrong place?

Comment: This time, try rebuild instead of make.

Comment: Wow, now it's generated a log file with this note:

`19:14:18.332 [Daemon Thread 29] INFO  o.a.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:85 - Initialize AndroidAnnotations 3.0.1 with options {androidManifestFile=/home/kayan/AndroidRefs/LetsApp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, resourcePackageName=com.kayan.letsapp}`

But it's not working yet

Comment: Also the directory doesn't exists

Comment: Try importing [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/gradle) project. Is it working?

Comment: I was able to import it, and run clean, build, make... still nothing happens...

Comment: @Hades no, I've found this :
http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
But I didn't have time to import it, at least the code gets cleaner.

Comment: Guys, please post your build gradle, or better the project, so we can check your problem.

Comment: Look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705318/android-annotations-with-android-studio/27079797#27079797