# Android Annotations with android studio

Tags: android, android-annotations

I've been trying to get Android Annotations working on Android Studio v0.8.14 along with Android Annotations 3.1. But for some reason it's not generating the required files. Can someone point me to the right documentation or steps I need to get a project set up.

I've looked around, nothing seems solid.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration). Check out the *Gradle* section. Also we have an [example project](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/gradle) which can be imported into AS out of the box.

Comment: @WonderCsabo had a look at it, seems okay, except I'm migrating a Eclipse project and trying to maintain both builds...will comment again if I can't get it set up...and thanks for the repyl!

Comment: @Hades I am using 0.8.14 and I can generate the classes from annotations in the apt build folder

Comment: @cooldman224 yeah I got it working...thanks guys...the tricky part was because I was exporting a project off eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Create root and app build.gradle like:

https://gist.github.com/Pierry/b3eab411c8865573b985

In activity, annotate this with `@EActivity(R.layout.activity_my)`, and add library in your classpath (Android studio make automatically), (Right click).

Add in your manifest _ after activity name.

Note: when u change everything in buidle.gradle, usually the line is removed:

```
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

You need add it again.
Verify always.

Comment: Why do you added those things to your root gradle file? You should only add the necessary things in root, and only declare the deps where they are used (in the app).

Comment: Show me your root file pls!

Comment: Please note your root gradle is totally incorrect. It adds Android nature to all modules, add APT and AA code generation etc. If you have for example a jar lib module and and app module, this gradle would add APK packaging and all that stuff and AA code generation to the simple jar module, too. Of course there can be a use case where this is needed, but i doubt this is the case here.

Comment: Ah ok! i agree, but not works for me, do you can show what i need change in my files?
https://gist.github.com/Pierry/b3eab411c8865573b985
Thanks!!

Comment: Check out our [example](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/gradle). You can use my root gradle with that (some parts regarding the repsitories can be removed from the example app gradle with the root gradle).

Comment: How about the:
"Error: Could not find property 'processResources' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@48f217d0."
that points to:
"androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile"   ?

Comment: @Jakub The line in your gradle file should now be `androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile`

Comment: Yea, I've noticed that ;)